# Store a python datetime timestamp so that I can later query all events from that date

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I have been reading every doc and SO question I could find for two days now and have not figured it out. The problem I am having seems simple however I simply can not understand the answers well enough to put it together.

I have a site I built that is running on Heroku. It is built in flask.
When someone makes a purchase the customer object in my postgress db is timestamped with a timestamp without timezone table. for this I am using:

```
now=datetime.now()
```

This sets a time that was fine while testing on my local machine, but now is off due to my servertime being 7 hours off on UTC time. 
 The problem I see is that if I store the timestamp as:

```
now=datetime.utcnow()
```

The time stored in the DB will still be in UTC time and I do not understand how I could query all transactions that happened today.
Currently I use a filter that is >=today and <=tomorrow. So when the timestamp is in UTC time all transactions after 6:00 pm are stored to the following date

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it up with those:

```
from datetime import datetime

import pytz
import tzlocal


def get_stamp()->float:
    return datetime.timestamp(datetime.now())


def stamp_to_utc(stamp:float)->datetime:
    naive_local = datetime.fromtimestamp(stamp) 
    local_tz = pytz.timezone(tzlocal.get_localzone().zone)
    return local_tz.localize(naive_local).astimezone(pytz.utc)

def utc_to_tz(utc_dt, tz_name)->datetime:
    return utc_dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone(tz_name))

def main():
    stamp = get_stamp()  # store this in db
    stamp_dt_utc = stamp_to_utc(stamp)
    print(stamp_dt_utc)
    stamp_dt_arizona = utc_to_tz(stamp_dt_utc, "US/Arizona")
    print(stamp_dt_arizona)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I still do not understand how any of those will solve my issue? I need the timestamp to be set to Arizona time and not  local time of where my server is located when I am storing the event.

Comment: Store as float in the db, convert it to UTC when reading from DB, convert to desired tz After you are already UTC otherwise the conversions won't be accurate.

Comment: Generaly in programming 'timestamp's are UTC-based and you might want to read more on the topic.